# Weblogic slow server startup and publishing

Tags: weblogic12c

I am using Weblogic 12.2.1.3 on Windows 10 to deploy a web application (war) of size ~200 mb.
I have around 3 GB allocated to Weblogic server in setDomainEnv.cmd. The problem is server startup and application deploy takes more than 30 minutes.

How can I speed up abd reduce the time?

I have tried setting different random generator in java.security file but it didn't help.
I have also try disabling xml validation but it didnt help either.

Any pointers on troubleshooting slow start up times?

Thanks

Comment: You can take several thread dumps during start up to see what the server is doing.
Also, you can try to start your server in Windows admin mode.

Comment: Some weeks ago I saw a similar problem. At the end it was a problem with DNS. Could you look for "SYN_SENT" scokets (using netstat) while the server is trying to start? This happened after configuring Active Directory.

Comment: Did you pre-compile the war file before deploying it?